# How can I understand the step by step calculations for the formula from the blog below?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recreational-mathematics, education, mathematical-physics

I am studying clustering and found a useful article on the blog post here [Finding the K in K-Means](https://datasciencelab.wordpress.com/2013/12/27/finding-the-k-in-k-means-clustering/).
But I am having difficulty in understanding the formulas below and how I can do step by step calculations. I hope somebody can help me out with this. My apologies if I have place my post in the wrong places here.

[image]

Comment: What is $W_k$ ?

Comment: I have uploaded the full pdf image. Thank you for taking a look at it.

Comment: Also take a look at stats.stackexchange.com, and http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/93481/artificial-intelligence